# MySQL database design: multiple values in the same field

Tags: mysql, indexing

I need to create an index on 3 columns:

```
`gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`age` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
`is_looking_for` varchar(30) NOT NULL default ''
```

The problem is third column which is VARCHAR and this index will not be used. I can't make it INT. Each user who creates a profile in this dating site answers question "I am looking for.." and she/he can select multiple options, for exmple,
*looking for male

looking for female or couple (female+female)

looking for male or female, couple (male+female)*

Now i store this information in a VARCHAR (is_looking_for) field in this way:

```
1,3,5
```

and MySQL query looks like this:

```
select from profiles where gender='$gender' and age between $minage and $maxage 
and is_looking_for LIKE '%$lookingfor%';
```

This query is very bad but I don't know how to resolve this problem. I don't want to create different columns for each gender option - male, female, couple(m+f), couple(f+f) etc. because then I need to create multiple indexes - a separate index for each gender:

```
KEY `gender` (`gender`,`age`,`female`)
KEY `gender_1` (`gender`,`age`,`male`)
KEY `gender_2` (`gender`,`age`,`couple_male_female`)
```

etc.

I had an idea to assign an unique number to each possible combination and then to store this number in a INT field but I gave up because it's too difficult.

Can help somebody? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize your design. Create  a separate table that lists all those "looking for" variables, each with their own unique ID.

```
1. looking for male
2. looking for female
3. looking for male+female
4. looking for ...
```

Then another table that links this new table to your dating table:

```
date_id    looking_for_id
69         2
69         4
```

which would signify that date #69 is looking for a female, or a ...

Comment: Thanks, I will do that if I don't find another solution. I am just trying to avoid selects from multiple tables.

Comment: Marc B, can you please show me an example of this join query? I don't know how to join on 2 statements. Select profiles.userid, profiles.nick from profiles join lookingforTable on profiles.userid=lookingforTable.date_id where profiles.gender='$gender' and age between $minage and $maxage.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create an ENUM. The ENUM is meant for that.

Take a look at the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Since looking_for can have multiple values, perhaps `set` is more appropriate than `enum`

Comment: hair raisin, yes, I could use "SET" but do I need to create a multicolumn Index. I think that MySQL will not use such a multicolumn index:  tinyint+tinyint+set. "SET" is not an integer. I am wrong?